# Dynamic typing of foreach variable

Tags: c#, foreach

In the following code, How can I pass the type of variable to the nested foreach statement? 
getControls is a recursive function that returns a list of controls (wow!)

```
getControls(String type, Control donde)  

var tipos = new List<Type>() { typeof(Button), typeof(KryptonTextBox) };

foreach (Type t in tipos)
{
  List<Control> controls = getControls(t.ToString(), this);
  foreach (***** c in controls)
  {
    c.StateCommon.Back.Color1 = Color.White;
  }    
}
```

Comment: Um... "Button" doesn't have a "StateCommon" member.  You won't able to run that code on the returned buttons.

Comment: @Joel You don't know what actual type Button is, so that's hard to say definitively.

Comment: I wouldn't use exception handling to control flow :p Just use the is operator to ensure the object is of the type you are looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The iterating variable needs to be of a compatible type to the list item types.

Thus the compiler only allows you to write

```
foreach(Control c in controls)
```

but inside the foreach block, you can use type casts to call methods of a specific type:

```
{
    if (c is MyControlType)
        (c as MyControlType).StateCommon.Back.Color1 = Color.White;
}
```

Comment: -1: Other that the fact that you are syntactically allowed to put an `is`/`as` inside the block, this is simply wrong. First, the compatibility of the foreach variable can include up, down, or interface casts. Second, when you do use `is`/`as`, you should use `as` followed by a null check instead.

Answer (score 7):

The `foreach` statement can cast the enumeration variable:

```
IEnumerable objects = ...;
foreach (AnyTypeHere i in objects)
    ...

IEnumerable<Button> buttons = ...;
foreach (MySpecialButton button in buttons)
    ...
```

This will work as long as *all* of the buttons in the enumeration are of type `MySpecialButton` than derives from `Button`. If you don't know that, then you can enumerate over only the buttons of type `MySpecialButton` like this:

```
IEnumerable<Button> buttons = ...;
foreach (MySpecialButton button in buttons.OfType<MySpecialButton>())
    ...
```

`OfType` differs from `Cast` in that it filters the enumeration rather than throwing an exception when an object is of a type that cannot be cast to the target type.

Comment: This is a good way of doing it. The OfType<T>() extension method is handy for lists of differing types.

Answer (score 1):

If you only reference values available on the supertype (Control) inside the foreach, then just declare it as Control.

If you have type-specific logic, you'll still need to declare it as Control, but then figure out which type you're dealing with in each iteration and use casts and conditional logic.

One way to do that is to refactor the body of the foreach into a set of methods (i.e. Update(Button), Update(KryptonTextBox)) and just call Update(c).

Answer (score 1):

The foreach variable needs to match the list type.

```
foreach(Control c in controls)
```

or

```
foreach(Object c in controls)
```

I am guessing that since you pass in the list of types to getControls, that it only returns controls of that type, but if not you will need to validate the type

```
if(t.IsAssignableFrom(c))
```

You would then need to use reflection to set the properties.